# Binary Number Divisible by N using Single Logic Gate

Tags: binary, logical-operators, integer-division, state-diagram

Given a 16-bit register A holding a number in 2’s complement form, use a single gate (e.g., AND, OR,
XOR, NAND, NOR, NOT) with an arbitrary number of inputs to implement a circuit that produces an
output 1 if the number is divisible by 16, and an output 0 otherwise. The bits are labelled A15, A14, ..., A0.

It's only worth two marks so I'm not sure what the point of this exactly is,

My answer was a single XOR gate with inputs  from A0-a15 Any ideas?

Comment: Write out the representations of some numbers that **are** divisible by 16, and some that **aren't**.  What do you notice?

Comment: mhm i notice only a few bits are 1, so would it be an or gate?@OliverCharlesworth

Comment: theres no specific positions of 1's in the bit pattern @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: `only worth two marks so I'm not sure what the point of this exactly is` A low rating is an indication that answering *should* be easy: take the need to guess as a hint that you missed something.